# Create fixed sidebar (Doesn't Scroll) in WordPress WooCommerce Shop

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, sidebar

I have a WooCommerce site setup here: http://museiam.ca/shop/

I am trying to make the left sidebar fixed so it doesn't scroll and stays in the a fixed position. Essentially, only the products wrapper will scroll. I would also like if the menu floated near the middle of the page (vertically) so it is not close to the top nor bottom of the page.

Any input on how to go about doing this is appreciated. I have tried the following with no success:

```
.widget woocommerce widget_product_categories {
position:fixed !important;
}
```

Thank you all for reading.

Comment: You didn't say what browser you are using, and if mobile which OS?  Do you have an example we can see?

Comment: Hi. I used FF but also tested on chrome. The other solution worked but I was wondering how to adding padding underneath as well. See other comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.widget_product_categories {
  position: fixed;
  width: 180px; // to make sure, the container keep it's width
}
```

Tested and worked in Chrome

Comment: Hi. That worked great. Thank you.However do you know how to add padding to the bottom so there is still some white space beneath? See this page for example http://museiam.ca/product-category/men/